# How to integrate PayUMoney iOS SDK in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, payumoney

I've downloaded the PayUMoney iOS SDK from the PayUMoney website. I'm now unable to integrate the SDK with my swift project.

Comment: can you please share the download link where you got only sdk without integration instructions ?

Comment: https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html

This is where i got it

Comment: this PayU SDK doesn't seem to be reliable, go for PayPal SDK, it's very simple to use and the PayPal developer website offers an extensive documentation that helps you implement its SDK in your app.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is taken from PayU documentation itself, i am answering here just because it took me hours to implement with their documentation.

Hi i can guide you with NON seamless integration.
https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/8.-iOS-SDK-integration#nonseamless

In non seamless integration PayU is already providing UI and will handle the card type and all payment process and at the end you will be notified for the status of your transaction with reason if failed and all details.

Download the SDK from Here:https://github.com/payu-intrepos/iOS-SDK-Sample-App/archive/3.8.1.zip

From Sample code copy file from "BusinessLayer" folder.

So i hope you have all required files now we can go further with integration.

You are integrating PayU with swift, as there is no swift SDK is not present from PayU team we have to proceed with Briding to Objective-C .
You can find about this here:[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24002369/3548469)

Once header file is created and configured in build setting, import the following Headers of SDK

```
#import "PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
#import "PUUIPaymentOptionVC.h"
#import "PUSAWSManager.h"
#import "PUSAWSManager.h"
#import "PUSAHelperClass.h"
```

Now we are ready to use PayU SDK into our environment/project.

Create new instance of 3 main object used for payment
1)Payment parameters
2)Hash Values
2)Helperclass// to calculate hash value

paste this above your viewDidLoad()

```
let paymentParam: PayUModelPaymentParams  = PayUModelPaymentParams()
var hashes :PayUModelHashes  = PayUModelHashes()
let PUSAhelper:PUSAHelperClass = PUSAHelperClass()
```

Here is function i have created for further processing

```
func continueWithCardPayment()  {

        paymentParam.key = "gtKFFx"
        paymentParam.transactionID = "umangtxn123"
        paymentParam.amount = "100.0"
        paymentParam.productInfo = "Nokia"
        paymentParam.SURL = "https://google.com/"
        paymentParam.FURL = "https://facebook.com/"
        paymentParam.firstName = "Umang"
        paymentParam.email = "umangarya336@gmail.com"
        paymentParam.environment = ENVIRONMENT_MOBILETEST
        paymentParam.udf1 = "udf1"
        paymentParam.udf2 = "udf2"
        paymentParam.udf3 = "udf3"
        paymentParam.udf4 = "udf4"
        paymentParam.udf5 = "udf5"
        paymentParam.offerKey = ""              // Set this property if you want to give offer:
        paymentParam.userCredentials = ""

        PUSAhelper.generateHashFromServer(self.paymentParam) { (hashes, errorString) in
            self.hashes = hashes
            self.paymentParam.hashes = hashes
            self.callPaymentGateway()
        }
    }

    func callPaymentGateway()  {

        let webServiceResponse :PayUWebServiceResponse = PayUWebServiceResponse()

        webServiceResponse.getPayUPaymentRelatedDetailForMobileSDK(paymentParam) { (paymentDetail, errString, extraParam) in

            if errString == nil {

                let payOptionVC: PUUIPaymentOptionVC = loadVC("PUUIMainStoryBoard", strVCId: VC_IDENTIFIER_PAYMENT_OPTION) as! PUUIPaymentOptionVC

                payOptionVC.paymentParam = self.paymentParam
                payOptionVC.paymentRelatedDetail = paymentDetail

                runOnMainThread({
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.paymentResponseReceived(_:)), name: kPUUINotiPaymentResponse, object: nil)
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(payOptionVC, animated: true)
                })
            }
            else{
                print("Failed to proceed for payment : \(errString)")
            }
        }
    }
```

There are some My custom function that will through error at your side you copy paste, i am mentioning them here. Do take care of them

1)loadVC("PUUIMainStoryBoard", strVCId: VC_IDENTIFIER_PAYMENT_OPTION)
//Loadvc function i have created to load view controller, you have to change it as you call your view controller

2)runOnMainThread({
// This function is for running code on main thread.

I have used all test credentials provided by PayU team
you can find more in their doc :https://www.payumoney.com/pdf/PayUMoney-Technical-Integration-Document.pdf

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.paymentResponseReceived(_:)), name: kPUUINotiPaymentResponse, object: nil)
```

//With this line we are adding notification sent by payment gateway to notify us regarding the status of the payment process, lets cash the notification.

```
func paymentResponseReceived(notify:NSNotification) {
print(notify)
}
```

You will get the response in notify.object.
You can find more sophisticated language and way at their document:https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/8.-iOS-SDK-integration.

Hope this answer may help you.

Comment: i did try this. I'm getting an error from the bridging header, saying that "file not found"

Comment: it says, "PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h" file not found in the bridging header

Comment: Check for PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h file in folder you dragged.

Comment: If there is no such file in sdk then download sample project and get file from thr. In terms of payment integration PayU sucks'

Comment: I did add all the libraries needed. But then the libraries are not linked.

Comment: Any luck? I am using the above way and in my app it is working

Comment: PUSAhelper.generateHashFromServer giving error: unresolved method name generateHashFromServer in PUSAHelperClass

Comment: got the solution Used PUSAhelper.generateHashFromServer() now its working.

Comment: generateHasFromServer , we should not use this method instead ask your backend developer to create one.

Comment: Its not working with Xcode 8.3.3. Getting linker error

Comment: @Mamta -  Payu have now provided SDK for swift. Try that instead. Let me know if you are still facing issue.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel thanks for informing! Please could you provide the link here

Comment: https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/New-Swift-SDK---Seamless